# handle POST without body

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I am writing a REST service using JAX-RS 2.0 to mimic an existing HTTP interface.

This includes POSTing an empty request against a path and later POSTing content to the same Path.

Right now my Resource looks like this:

```
@Path("data")
public class MyResource {
  @Inject
  MyService service;

  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  public byte[] init() {
    return service.init();
  }

  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  public byte[] work(byte[] data) {
    return service.work(data);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when the client tries to POST its init, the following error occurs:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: content-type was null and expecting to extract a body into public javax.ws.rs.core.Response rest.MyResource.work(byte[])
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:131)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:252)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:217)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:206)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:514)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:491)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:140)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:204)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is there a way to solve this via JAX-RS or do I have to fall back to Servlets to handle this particular situation?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem. Consider this JAX-RS method:

```
@POST
@Path("/bytes")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response postOctetStream(byte[] bytes) {
    return Response.ok(bytes.length).build();
}
```

Consider this `curl` call:

```
$ curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -d "" http://localhost:8080/WebApplication4/webresources/bytes
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /WebApplication4/webresources/foo/bytes HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
> Content-Length: 0
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
< Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0 
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2013 10:56:55 GMT
< Content-Length: 1
<
```

As you can see, the client sets `Content-Length: 0`. The server can map this empty body to a zero-length `byte[]`.